# Changing the Capital letters in TabPageIndicator android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

Hi I am working with [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/)

In the TabPageIndicator the title is fully capital.

[image]

1) How to change to "Example" format?
2) If a title has space (like two words) its not showing fully.
   For example, if I am giving a title as "Recently Played", it appears as "RECENTLY" only.

Comment: Even in the homepage there is a screenshot with the desired output for 1). Maybe you added `android:textAllCaps` on the layout by mistake?

Comment: @EvripidisDrakos No. I didn't used the textAllCaps attribute.

Comment: you should post the related code then to get an answer